# Getting average volume for multiple coins within certain interval using sockets or REST

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance, cryptocurrency

I am trying to get an average volume within certain interval of time using Binance `API`. For example, I want to have an `average volume` where time range would be defined like this (pseudo code):

```
startTime = now() - 24h - 20 min
endTime = now() - 20 min
```

And I have to do this for 200 trading pairs (eg all `USDT` related trading pairs).

I know I can make one `API` call per symbol (https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data) to get this data using `REST`, like this:

```
  async function getKline(marketSymbol, timeInterval, limit) {
    var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=' + marketSymbol
                   + '&interval=' + timeInterval
                   + '&startTime' + startTime
                   + '&endTime' + endTime
                   + '&limit=' + limit;
    
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    
    return data;
  }
```

But cause I have to do this every minute, it would be 200 `API` calls per minute. And I am already using sockets to fetch candlestick data every two seconds for 200 pairs.

So I guess using `REST` api/v3/klines is not performant or a way to go here. I mean I know this request has a request `weight` that equals to `1`, and I would be probably fine with restrictions and limits, but, is there some other way to go to get average volume within certain interval for multiple coins like in one single request, or in any way other than making that much `API` calls every minute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using socket for 200 pairs you don't need any other API call. This is the socket response for klines:

```
{
  "e": "kline",     // Event type
  "E": 123456789,   // Event time
  "s": "BTCUSDT",    // Symbol
  "k": {
    "t": 123400000, // Kline start time
    "T": 123460000, // Kline close time
    "s": "BTCUSDT",  // Symbol
    "i": "1m",      // Interval
    "f": 100,       // First trade ID
    "L": 200,       // Last trade ID
    "o": "0.0010",  // Open price
    "c": "0.0020",  // Close price
    "h": "0.0025",  // High price
    "l": "0.0015",  // Low price
    "v": "1000",    // Base asset volume
    "n": 100,       // Number of trades
    "x": false,     // Is this kline closed?
    "q": "1.0000",  // Quote asset volume
    "V": "500",     // Taker buy base asset volume
    "Q": "0.500",   // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "B": "123456"   // Ignore
  }
}
```

so you have all data that you need. You can save all candlestick from the websocket and calculate the mean of volumes. In this way if you have to calculate volume mean in 24h you need to wait 24h data collection, otherwise you can create a first configuration method that is called for first that cal all 200 symbols historical data with weight calculation. If 150 calls is bigger then the maximum weight you have to wait a minutes for other 50 calls.

Unfortunatly binance doesn't support multi symbols calls

Comment: Yeah storing data and waiting for 24h can work. But what do you think, I just wonder, cause I never did it, if the running of 200 API calls in a for loop would be ok? I mean we can make 1200 request weights per minute. I have 200 APi calls that have request weight 1 per call. But still I am a bit afraid to run them, how to say, in bulk (like in a for loop one after another)? Do you think that would be safe?

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing a bit, I dunno how to explain it better.

Comment: It's ok to do all 200 calls in a for loop but you have to create a weight variable increased at each call and decreased at each call and u have to wait that the weight is decreased when It reaches the maximum possible. And it's very hard if you prefer to do all this stuff in an asynchronous way. Instead in synchronous way it can take a very long period to finish all the calls

Comment: I am collecting 1m candlestick info for all symbols in Binance SPOT Market in a for loop and it works fine, but it takes around 25 sec to get the info. @Whirlwind sorry but, could I ask you some guidance in how to approach the websockets combined stream data retrieval? I have an issue while asking for 377 symbols data becasue I get instead 320 pairs... Any comment would be highly appreciated :) I leave here a link to a question I posted. Thanks in advance! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75788322/problems-with-combined-stream-of-data-by-using-binance-api